# Who has filming rights for Squirrel Girl?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, x-men-cinematic-universe, copyright

Squirrel Girl is a very popular Marvel comics character, but I never heard about any live action adaptation in any development. She was considered a mutant too but then came out as not being one. So I wanted to know who really has the filming rights for Squirrel Girl, is it Fox or Disney? Or any other studio? Has it ever been discussed and cleared officially?

Comment: don't forget there are 2 Quicksilvers. one in the MCU and one in X-Men, same powers but one is a mutant and one isn't. unless Squirrel Girl is named herself i would suspect that if Marvel Studios wanted to use her they'd make her not a mutant while Fox could keep her as one

Comment: @Memor-X Mutant twin's case was pretty public but Squirrel Girl more of got retcon to became non mutant, so it can fall under both or any studio but I wanted to get some official answer.

Comment: @Memor-X IIRC Scarlet Witch and Quicksilver are specifically named in the Fox agreement as having this special exemption, as they were both X-Men and core Avengers.

Comment: @OrangeDog oh i see. so it would be more of the reverse of what i suggested

Comment: I remember a few years ago I was watching an animated Spiderman Show and there was a character named Squirrel Girl in an episode, which I though they just made up for that episode because squirrel powers seem so silly.  And then one time I looked up Squirrel Girl and found she was a real Marvel character.  So if someone as silly sounding as Squirrel Girl can be a Marvel hero and defeat Doctor Doom in her first appearance, I guess she can appear in a live action movie or show sooner or later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Freeform announced a Marvel TV Show, *New Warriors*, and included Squirrel Girl in the line up.  She was cast and played by Milana Vayntrub.

Excerpt from link:

> It’s unclear if New Warriors will take place in the Marvel Cinematic
> Universe, as it will be Marvel’s first comedy TV series since it began
> producing its own content in Hollywood. The tone of the series will
> probably determine whether the show can work in the MCU. The Marvel
> films have a lot of comedy, but they never become outright farcical.
> If New Warriors goes for that kind of comedy then it may not fit in
> with the larger MCU

Based on the above, I'd have to say the rights must belong to Marvel/Disney.

Full details can be found [here](https://archive.nerdist.com/marvels-new-warriors-tv-series-reveals-squirrel-girl/)

[The pilot was produced, but not shown, and was sent back to Marvel Television](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Warriors_(TV_pilot)), where Disney+ and Hulu refused it, and [the project is likely dead as of 2019](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/tv/tv-news/ghost-rider-drama-marvel-tv-dead-at-hulu-1243409/).